# Parse UIButton into method in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have some methods that interact with the UIButtons in my view controller, with a lot of repetitive code. Here's an example of one of those methods:

```
-(void)spinButtons {
CABasicAnimation *fullRotation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
fullRotation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
fullRotation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:((360*M_PI)/180)];
fullRotation.duration = 3;
fullRotation.repeatCount = 0;


[_button1.layer addAnimation:fullRotation forKey:@"360"];
[_button2.layer addAnimation:fullRotation forKey:@"360"];
[_button3.layer addAnimation:fullRotation forKey:@"360"];
[_button4.layer addAnimation:fullRotation forKey:@"360"];
[_button5.layer addAnimation:fullRotation forKey:@"360"];
[_button6.layer addAnimation:fullRotation forKey:@"360"];
```

}

Is there a way how I can store the name of the buttons in an NSdictionary, list etc so i can turn the above into this:

```
-(void)spinButtons:(UIButton *)button {
CABasicAnimation *fullRotation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
fullRotation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
fullRotation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:((360*M_PI)/180)];
fullRotation.duration = 3;
fullRotation.repeatCount = 0;

[button.layer addAnimation:fullRotation forKey:@"360"];
```

}

I Hope this makes sense!

Comment: Don't use names, just store the buttons themselves in a list.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Interface Builder, you could construct an `IBOutletCollection` to which you would add all of your buttons.

As far as I know, this isn't ordered, so if order is important to you, you might have to find a different way.

Comment: It isn't guaranteed to be ordered but I've found it to be ordered by the time they were added into the `IBOutletCollection`. So the first item added is at index 0 and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [KVC](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html).

```
[[self valueForKeyPath:"button1.layer"] addAnimation:fullRotation forKey:@"360"];
```

So for the array

```
NSArray *layers = @["button1.layer", "button2.layer", "button3.layer", "button4.layer", "button5.layer", "button6.layer"];
for (NSString *layer in layers) {
    [[self valueForKeyPath:layer] addAnimation:fullRotation forKey:@"360"];
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

To set a value with KVC, you can use `-setValue:forKeyPath:`.

For example, to set a button:

```
[self setValue:[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem] forKeyPath:"button1"];
```

Things get more complex for non-object types: these get wrapped in objects like `NSValue` and `NSNumber`. For example, a `button1.frame` is a `CGRect`… which is a `struct`. `CGRect`s are placed in `NSValue` wrappers.

Here is using KVC to get a frame.

```
CGRect frame = [[self valueForKeyPath:"button1.frame"] CGRectValue];
```

The same thing must be done when using `-setValue:forKeyPath:`.

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
[self setValue:[NSValue valueWithCGRect:frame] forKeyPath:"button1.frame"];
```

Comment: This did the trick - thank you for your awesomeness.                                            Can I use the same concept with properties of objects?    E.g button1.frame = xxx   button2.frame=xxx